# Changing the domain name causes my image to not load in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

I have recently changed my wordpress installation a bit. I have configred IIS to have the website run as an application under a common domain name i have for multiple website.

So the main website name is www.example.com

The application is configured as www.example.com/sitename

Now i can access the site as www.example.com/sitename but all the images on the site have the src as "/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" which causes the links to be broken as they point to www.example.com/wp-content.... instead of www.example.com/sitename/wp-content . how can i fix this.

I have tried the following.

1. Change the wp_options table. Set SiteURL and home to  http://www.example.com/sitename
2. Changed the Wp-Config.php file with the following parameters.

   - define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
   - define('MULTISITE', false);
   - define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
   - define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.abs-projects.co.uk/absuk');
   - define('WP_HOME','http://www.abs-projects.co.uk/absuk');
   - define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.abs-projects.co.uk/absuk');
   - define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');

Comment: Did you follow this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WP Migrate DB or Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin to update all occurrences of 'www.example.com' to 'www.example.com/sitename' throughout the whole database. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ensure that you have set the `siteurl` and `home` options in the `{tableprefix}_options` table to the new URL in your database **without** an ending `/`. if that doesn't do it, your theme will need to be updated. precede each path to an image with

```
<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg
```

alternatively, since you have constants in your wp-config.php file,

```
<?php echo WP_HOME; ?>/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg
```